# How can delete whitespaces from object in sql to check some condition using where

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have tried to trim "appointment" to check if it is equal to string that I have sent by trim function from ajax. But trim('appointment') doesn't give me what I need. How can delete whitespaces from object in sql to check some condition using where

```php
public function category_filter(Request $request)
{
    $appointment = json_decode($request->appointment);
    $categories = [];
    foreach($appointment as $a){
        $cat_c_id = Products::where(trim('appointment'), '=', $a)->select('id')->get();
        foreach($cat_c_id as $cat_c){
            array_push($categories, $cat_c);
        }
    }
    var_dump($categories);
}
```

Comment: `trim('appointment')` looks like its already trimmed, you have to check your `$a` values its same as `appointment`.

Comment: How about `trim('appointment'), '=', 'trim($a)`

Comment: *How can delete whitespaces from object in sql* What are problematic spaces? leading? trailing? multiple inner?

Comment: $a already trimmed in ajax

Comment: Akina I need to delete spaces, tabs, enters or smth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer here is to fix your data and not store it with whitespace in the first place. Failing that, you need to use a raw statement:

```php
public function category_filter(Request $request)
{
    $appointment = json_decode($request->appointment);
    $categories = [];
    foreach($appointment as $a) {
        $cat_c_id = Products::whereRaw('TRIM(appointment) = ?', [$a])
            ->select('id')
            ->get();
        foreach($cat_c_id as $cat_c){
            array_push($categories, $cat_c);
        }
    }
    var_dump($categories);
}
```

Taking it a step further, you are performing pointless `foreach` loops that can be replaced with something like this:

```php
public function category_filter(Request $request)
{
    $appointment = json_decode($request->appointment);
    // build a string like TRIM(appointment) IN (?,?,?,?)
    $raw = 'TRIM(appointment) IN (' . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($appointment), '?')) . ')';
    $categories = Products::whereRaw($raw, $appointment)
        ->select('id')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
    }
    var_dump($categories);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
trim('appointment') //this will trim the string 'appointment', not its value on table
```

try this (considering that Products::where allow this type of implementation):

```
...
$cat_c_id = Products::where('trim(appointment)', '=', trim($a))->select('id')->get();
...
```

Comment: It also didn't work. I have solved my problem by str_replace function of php.                        `$cat_c_id = Products::all();}`                                                                                  `str_replace(' ', '', $cat_c->appointment)`